Does the HotD Season 2 intro tapestry with a dragon and two figures reference an event in ASoIaF lore?
In the opening credits to House of the Dragon Season 2, we see a series of tapestries depicting various events related to House Targaryen. In episode 3’s intro, one tapestry shows what looks like a dragon with a bloodied head and two people near it. One person (who seems to be shirtless) is holding something in front of the dragon, while the other is clutching a bloodied knife or dagger and a bowl.


Are there any specific events or characters from the A Song of Ice and Fire universe that this tapestry could be alluding to?

If the unarmed person was a woman, it could have been final moment of Rhaenyra since she was pricked with a knife to make Sunfyre roused. But as it is, it may be alluding to Storming of the Dragonpit. No other event comes to mind
